# www.api.domain.com leads to one page and api.domain.com leads to another. www.domain.com works but domain.com doesn't. What gives?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have the following Apache virtual hosts config file called 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:3000/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I am facing the 2 following issues and I'm not sure if the problem is on Apache's side or on the DNS's side:

1. When I visit [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) , I see the page that I am supposed to
   be seeing but if I try typing just domain.com in the search bar, I
   get an error - This site can’t provide a secure connection
2. When I visit api.mydomain.com , I see the correct page which I'm
   supposed to be seeing BUT when I try [www.api.mydomain.com](http://www.api.mydomain.com) , I get
   the page that is supposed to be on [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) instead.

Can anyone shine some light on whether this is a result of bad Apache configuration or I need to do something on the DNS?

Comment: Looks like a configuration question (see the [tag:apache] tag description that declares those questions as off topic on stackoverflow. Also: You provide port 80 config, and an error message about a "secure connection", and in the configuration snippet that you provide you're not even configuring all host names that you would like to behave a specific way (e.g. `www.api...`)

Comment: @OlafKock Hmmm why do you say that I'm not even configuring all host names that I would like to behave a specific way? The second virtual host with ServerName api.mydomain.com is supposed to handle the API.

Comment: You state that on `api.*` everything is fine, but on `www.api.*` it's not. I don't see any config for `www.api.*`. And I don't see anything for https

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add two lines to your /etc/apache2/.conf

```
ServerAlias www.domain.com
```

Add this line under the ServerName